# lost time and lost money

Tags: phrase-usage, idiomatic-language

Are "lost time" and "lost money" common, idiomatic expressions? What article should be used with them?

For example:

> Before starting to work you need to make sure all requirements are discussed. Because time spent on implementing something different from what a customer expected is a **lost time** and **lost money**.

If not, could you provide other expressions that are close in meaning to these ones?

Comment: Thank you for the answer!

Comment: I've provided an extended version as an *actual* Answer rather than a comment (which some mods and other others disapprove of). I don't need the rep points, but I'm sure those who disapprove would much prefer you to "Accept" my answer and delete your comment. (You could even *upvote* it if you want! :)

Answer (score -1):

Ignoring other Off Topic "proofreading" aspects of my earlier comment, ***Yes*** - the sequence [**lost time and lost money**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22lost%20time%20and%20lost%20money%22) is perfectly idiomatic (and *common,* as shown by many written instances in that link).

It's also common (but not *required*) to "delete" the second (predictably repeated) instance of ***lost*** in such constructions, but no article should be present - it's just *[blah blah] **is lost time and money***.

It's actually [far more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=waste%20of%20time%20and%20money%2Clost%20time%20and%20money&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwaste%20of%20time%20and%20money%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clost%20time%20and%20money%3B%2Cc0) to convey that "negating" link between ***time, money,*** and some "futile, non-productive" activity by saying it's [*a **waste** of time and money*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22a%20waste%20of%20time%20and%20money%22). But that's a bit more "dogmatically belittling", so you should avoid it unless you actually *want* to be slightly "rude, dismissive".

Finally, it's worth pointing out that ***time and money*** is something of an ["irreversible binomial"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_pair) (like *horse and cart, deaf and dumb, bread and water*) - so [you won't often encounter ***money and time***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=time%20and%20money%2Cmoney%20and%20time&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctime%20and%20money%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmoney%20and%20time%3B%2Cc0) in that order.